# Get address of pixel in bitmap display MIPS

Tags: assembly, mips, mars-simulator

I'm using the bitmap display of the [MARS-simulator](http://courses.missouristate.edu/KenVollmar/mars/index.htm) with unit width 16px, and startaddress $gp.
How would I get the address of a specific pixel using coordinates?

Example (x,y)
I guess I just have to count the amount of pixels until I get to (x,y) and use that as offset on $gp?

Pseudo:

```
>ColAmount = 32 #RowLength
>RowAmount = 16 #ColumnHeight
>x = 4
>y = 5
Coordinate = (x, y)
AmountOfPixelsUntilCoordinate = (RowAmount * y) + ColAmount
offset = AmountOfPixelsUntilCoordinate
addressOfPixel = offset($gp)
```

Is this correct? How'd I implement this in MIPS ASM?

Comment: what video chip/solution are you using and how are the pixels mapped, bits per pixel, packing, etc?

Comment: @old_timer it's about MARS simulator "bitmap" tool-plugin, which has a bit weird controls (like you can't specify the pixel resolution directly, but you specify it indirectly by setting up "unit" size and "display" size).

Comment: should have specified that in the question not just a tag.  mips like arm is a core not a chip not a system, video questions are in no way whatsoever related to mips at all, they are related to what that core is connected to, which in this case is perhaps the simulated video in mars.   then mips questions get involved if they are asking assembly.  but this is a bad so question in that it didnt show any effort whatsoever.  this is not a homework service.

Comment: @old_timer I have specified that I'm working in MIPS, and am using the bitmap display

Comment: exactly that means nothing, mips is a processor core of which there are a million variants since every other computer engineer had to create one in college, and pretty much any video product can be connected to one, and of the video products, simulated or real, there is an endless number of answers to your question, even if using mars you still need to know the specs in order to do the math you are asking to do.  at the same time all you had to do is compile this and see what pops out.  where is the assembly you created that you are having issues with?

Comment: which variant of mips are you interested in there are different variants of the 32 bit instruction set and a 16 bit instruction set, then there are different assemblers with different syntaxes.

Comment: To say it another way the MIPS processor in general does not have video logic, video logic is something you add on to the MIPS ip inside or outside the chip when you make a mips based chip (or simulator same answer).  A MIPS processor doesnt have a bitmap display, it is something you add to a mips processor or an arm or an x86, etc...

Comment: @old_timer: don't be too hard on the OP, this is tagged `[mars-simulator]`, so it's 32-bit classic MIPS (with no branch-delay slots) with the simulator's bitmap display thing.  @ O'Niel: it would have been better to mention specifically that you're using the bitmap thing built-in to MARS, and maybe linked to the MARS docs about it for people who know MIPS but not that simulator.

Comment: @O'Niel added example which makes ball flying at (x, y) coordinates (added to my previous example of drawing border+background, so the code is a bit longer, but the offset calculation is quite self-contained roughly in the middle of the source). (all is commented to the extend where I think it is enough, but let me know if these examples don't work for you for whatever reason, and what are you missing).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must provide also display size. i.e. 16x16 "unit" with 512x256 "display" means the actual bitmap resolution is 32x16 pixels (512/16, 256/16).

Then the "**index** of pixel(x, y)" is `y * 32 + x` => what you have in question. But to get memory **offset**, you have to accommodate for the size of single pixel, which takes whole `word`, so `offset = 4 * index`.

Final memory address is the `$gp + offset`.

You got it almost right, just the *4 is missing (of course for *4 don't use multiplication, but left shit by 2: `sll $<offset_reg>, $<index_reg>, 2`).  (and `*32` is "shift left by 5")

---

EDIT: Example of tracking something by (x, y) position (even with custom coordinate system, in this example "x" is same as bitmap 0..31 from left to right, but "y" is from 0..15 from bottom to top (bitmap is 0..15 from top to bottom).

The main part calculating memory offset and drawing pixel into Bitmap is after the comment:

```
# when ball is on the current row, draw it *now* (to minimize flickering)
```

How to run it: MARS4.5, verify "Delayed branching" is OFF, Tools->Bitmap Display and configure it to: 16x16 unit, 512x256 display (= bitmap size is then 32x16 pixels), and base address as `$gp`. Compile, run.

```
.data
ball_move_x:        .byte   -1
ball_move_y:        .byte   1

.text
.eqv    bounce_pos_y_min    1
.eqv    bounce_pos_y_max    14
.eqv    bounce_pos_x_min    1
.eqv    bounce_pos_x_max    30
.eqv    adjust_y_pos_xor    15
.eqv    ball_colour         0x00d0e0ff

    li      $t1, 0x00ff0000     #Loading RED in register
    li      $t2, 0x00ffff00     #Loading YELLOW in register
    li      $t3, 3              #"ball" x position
    li      $t4, 3              #"ball" y position (0->15 from bottom upward!)
    li      $t5, ball_colour
big_loop:
    # top row + first column
    move    $a0, $gp            # pointer to write to
    li      $a1, 33             # 32 pixels for first row, +1 for left column
    move    $a2, $t2            # yellow
    jal     setPixels
    # 14 red rows with yellow endings+starts
    li      $t0, 14
red_rows_loop:
    li      $a1, 30
    move    $a2, $t1
    jal     setPixels           # set 30 background pixels in middle
    # when ball is on the current row, draw it *now* (to minimize flickering)
    bne     $t4, $t0, skip_ball_draw
    xori    $at, $t4, adjust_y_pos_xor  # y pos goes from BOTTOM! -> flipping it
    # y ($t4) pos goes from bottom to make compare with count-down ($t0) simple
    # after flipping it, the $at has here real bitmap Y pos going 0->15 from top
    sll     $at, $at, 5         # calculate offset in $at: at = y_pos * 32
    add     $at, $at, $t3       # at = y_pos * 32 + x_pos = "index"
    sll     $at, $at, 2         # at = (y_pos * 32 + x_pos)*4 = "offset"
    add     $at, $at, $gp       # at = gp + offset
    sw      $t5, ($at)          # draw it!
    # W: dont't use $at unless you are sure the assembler will not destroy its content
    #    (pseudo instructions often do use it for partial calculations)
skip_ball_draw:
    # draw remaining border + next line border and loop for all lines
    sw      $t2, ($a0)          # set 1 yellow at end, and 1 at start of next row
    sw      $t2, 4($a0)
    addi    $a0, $a0, 8
    addi    $t0, $t0, -1
    bnez    $t0, red_rows_loop
    # finish last row to be full yellow
    li      $a1, 31             # 31 pixels more needed (1 is already there)
    move    $a2, $t2            # yellow
    jal     setPixels
    # update ball position x
    lb      $a0, ball_move_x
    beq     $t3, bounce_pos_x_min, ball_flip_x_dir
    bne     $t3, bounce_pos_x_max, ball_flip_x_dir_skip
ball_flip_x_dir:
    neg     $a0, $a0
    sb      $a0, ball_move_x    # store if flipped
ball_flip_x_dir_skip:
    add     $t3, $t3, $a0       # x += move_x
    # update ball position y
    lb      $a0, ball_move_y
    beq     $t4, bounce_pos_y_min, ball_flip_y_dir
    bne     $t4, bounce_pos_y_max, ball_flip_y_dir_skip
ball_flip_y_dir:
    neg     $a0, $a0
    sb      $a0, ball_move_y    # store if flipped
ball_flip_y_dir_skip:
    add     $t4, $t4, $a0       # y += move_y
    # short delay before next frame, and loop forever
    li      $v0, 32             # MARS service delay(ms)
    li      $a0, 40             # 40ms = ~25 FPS if the draw would be instant
    syscall
    addiu   $t1, $t1, 0xFE0408  # adjust background color (red -2, green +4, blue +8 + overflows (B -> G -> R)
    andi    $t1, $t1, 0xFFFFFF  # force "alpha" to zero
    j       big_loop            # infinite loop will animate colours...

# Sets $a1 pixels to $a2 value starting at $a0 (memory fill)
# a0 = pointer to write to, a1 = count of pixels, a2 = value of pixel to set
# a0 will be updated to point right after the last written word
setPixels:
    sw      $a2, ($a0)      # set pixel (or simply memory word)
    addi    $a0, $a0, 4     # advance memory pointer
    addi    $a1, $a1, -1    # count-down loop
    bnez    $a1, setPixels
    jr      $ra             # return
```